# Select Multiple Key Frames in Timeline Editor

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

How I can select multiple key frames in the timeline editor so that I can delete them all at once .​

Comment: You can't do that on the timeline, use the dopesheet or the graph editor,

Answer (score 1):

The timeline isn't actually an editor. It's simply a viewing port for all the keyframes in your animation. What you can do is:

1. Go to the **Graph editor** and select the objects that are keyframed
2. Move the playhead in the timeline to the keyframe you wish to delete
3. Hover your cursor over the graph editor and press **Ctrl-K**
4. Go to the next keyframe and repeat steps 2-3
5. Press **X** to delete the selected keyframes

**PLEASE NOTE** This process works if you want to delete all keyframed information about the selected objects. If, say, you just want to delete X-Location info but not Y-Location info, you have to manually select each keyframe in the Graph Editor.

Hope this helps!